# I use mdpi's latex template to generate pdf files, the first page of the file is not a summary, but a string of text that does not appear in the code

Tags: pdf

The first page of the generated pdf file looks like this.Very confusing text, I can't find this content in any code.
[image: Very confusing text, I can't find this content in any code]

The error reported when running the code is like this, but the PDF can be compiled completely, and there is no problem with the content, but the first page of the PDF is just like the first picture.
[image: The error reported when running the code is like this]

The following is part of my code, I deleted the comments in part of the code：

```
%  LaTeX support: latex@mdpi.com 
%  For support, please attach all files needed for compiling as well as the log file, and specify your operating system, LaTeX version, and LaTeX editor.

%=================================================================
\documentclass[journal,article,submit,pdftex,moreauthors]{Definitions/mdpi} 
\usepackage[UTF8]{ctex}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@maketitle}
{\hfill \href{https://www.mdpi.com}}
{\includegraphics[height=1cm]{Definitions/logo-electronics}\hfill \href{https://www.mdpi.com/electronics}}
{}{}
\makeatother
%=================================================================
% MDPI internal commands - do not modify
\firstpage{1} 
\makeatletter 
\setcounter{page}{\@firstpage} 
\makeatother
\pubvolume{1}
\issuenum{1}
\articlenumber{0}
\pubyear{2023}

\copyrightyear{2023}
%\externaleditor{Academic Editor: Firstname Lastname}
\datereceived{ } 
\daterevised{ } % Comment out if no revised date
\dateaccepted{ } 
\datepublished{ } 
%\datecorrected{} % For corrected papers: "Corrected: XXX" date in the original paper.
%\dateretracted{} % For corrected papers: "Retracted: XXX" date in the original paper.
\hreflink{https://doi.org/} % If needed use \linebreak
%\doinum{}
%\pdfoutput=1 % Uncommented for upload to arXiv.org


%=================================================================
% Full title of the paper (Capitalized)
\Title{Mathematical Named}

% MDPI internal command: Title for citation in the left column
\TitleCitation{Electronics}

% Authors, for the paper (add full first names)
\Author{Qiuyu $^{1,2}$}

%\longauthorlist{yes}

% MDPI internal command: Authors, for metadata in PDF
\AuthorNames{Qiu}

% MDPI internal command: Authors, for citation in the left column
\AuthorCitation{Qiu}
% If this is a Chicago style journal: Lastname, Firstname, Firstname Lastname, and Firstname Lastname.

% Affiliations / Addresses (Add [1] after \address if there is only one affiliation.)
\address{%
$^{1}$ \quad test1\\
$^{2}$ \quad test2\\
$^{3}$ \quad test3\\}
\corres{Correspondence:}

\abstract{Mathematical named}
\keyword{Named entity recognition; BiLSTM-CRF; Adversarial training; Self-attentive mechanism; Mathematical texts} 
\begin{document}
```

Comment: it looks like you have an old latex, but please show the error from the log file not an image of an editor. texstudio completely scrambles undefined command errors so you can not see which command is undefined, and other editors may be similar

Comment: If it helps anyone, I did a little bit of testing with the mdpi template that you can find in overleaf (I guess is the most up-to-date). The error happens for me in the code lines between (and including) `\usepackage[UTF8]{ctex}` to `\makeatother`

Comment: It seems like an attempt to patch the journal logo appearing on the top left of the paper. I would recommend the OP to directly use the MDPI template available on their webpage https://www.mdpi.com/authors/latex or in overleaf, and not worry about that. From my experience, it is added by the MDPI team after the work is accepted.

Comment: Thanks for everyone's help, I tried using other compilers and finally the error was solved